# How to grep a sentence with changing value in it

Tags: sed, grep, sentence

```
wget dnsleaktest.com
    cat index.html | grep -E -o "([0-9]{1,3}[.]){3}[0-9]{1,3}"
```

(grep out the IPv4)

Now I would like to grep the following out of the .html file:

```
<div class="home-container">
     <div class="welcome">
         <p class="hello">Hello 127.0.0.1</p>
         <p>from Dubai, United Arab Emirates
              <img class="flag" src="/assets/img/flags/ae.png" />
         </p>
```

The sentence "from Dubai, United Arab Emirates" but with every new 'wget' and the change of my public IPv4 the 'from Dubai, Untied Arab Emirates' changes of course.

Is there a way the grep that specific sentence? I cannot grep it correctly with `cat index.html | grep 'from Dubai, United Arab Emirates'`; I assume it's because I don't know the location.

I hope I was able to explain what I'm trying to do. Is there a way?

Comment: Not a robust way, but may work: `sed -n 's/.*<p>from \([^<]*\).*/\1/p' index.html`

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to parse html files with a regex. Use xml-aware tools.

Fro example:

```
curl -L dnsleaktest.com | xmllint --html --xpath 'string(//div[@class="welcome"]/p[2])' - 2>/dev/null
```

But using that specific site for geoip is strange. Firstly - you may install `geoip` from package manager. Secondly, for sure there are better sites that do not require parsing HTML, my first random hit on google is for example https://ipapi.co/#api .